# Objective-C: What is the difference between forKey and forKeyPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios

What is the difference between forKey and forKeyPath in NSMutableDicitionary's setValue method? I looked both up in the documentation and they seemed the same to me. I tried following code, but I couldn't distinguish the difference.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setValue:@"abc" forKey:@"ABC"];
[dict setValue:@"123" forKeyPath:@"xyz"];
for (NSString* key in dict) {
    id val = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", key, val);
}
```

Comment: Only different if you're using a more complex dictionary (with multiple levels). The reason yours looks the same is that a keypath with only one thing (no `.` indicating an additional path component) is actually just a key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both methods are part of [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) and should not generally be used for element access in dictionaries. They only work on keys of type `NSString` and require specific syntax.

The difference between both of them is that specifying a (single) key would just look up that item.

Specifying a key path on the other hand follows the path through the objects. If you had a dictionary of dictionaries you could look up an element in the second level by using a key path like `"key1.key2"`.

If you just want to access elements in a dictionary you should use `objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:`.

**Edit** to answer why `valueForKey:` should not be used:

1. `valueForKey:` works only for string keys. Dictionaries can use other objects for keys.
2. `valueForKey:` Handles keys that start with an "@" character differently. You cannot access elements whose keys start with `@`.
3. Most importantly: By using `valueForKey:` you are saying: "I'm using KVC". There should be a reason for doing this. When using `objectForKey:` you are just accessing elements in a dictionary through the natural, intended API.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason that `valueForKey:` should not be used with dictionaries?

Answer (score 3):

Apple Documentation: [NSKeyValueCoding Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

**setValue:forKey:**

Sets the property of the receiver specified by a given key to a given value.

*Example:*

```
[foo setValue:@"blah blah" forKey:@"stringOnFoo"];
```

**setValue:forKeyPath:**

Sets the value for the property identified by a given key path to a given value.

*Example:*

```
[foo setValue:@"The quick brown fox" forKeyPath:@"bar.stringOnBar"];
```

Comment: Also, when using "setValue:forKeyPath:" make sure the object at the keyPath exists. If it is nil, the method will silently fail because the path is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

`keyPath` can be used to traverse through arbitrary object paths, as long as they implement `NSKeyValueCoding`.  They don't need to be `NSDictionary`s.  For example:

```
NSString *departmentName = [self valueForKeyPath:@"[person.department.name"];
```

Although this is a bit of a contrived example.